# Using Unicode values in an access table and to concatenate label expression

Tags: python, function, unicode

I'm playing with unicode values in ArcGIS. Basically, I am trying to set a field in an access table that will store unicode values. I found this scripting example to encode unicode values.

```
import locale
locale.getdefaultlocale()
print u'Libert\u00e9'
```

This returns:

```
Liberté
```

With the accented é at the end

In my infinite wisdom, based on a very rookie experience with unicode encoding in python, I figured I could do this:

1. Create a text field in an access table
2. Populate that field with the unicode value, so u00e9
3. Define a python function like

Like this:

```
def FindLabel ( [Unicode] ):
  import locale
  locale.getdefaultlocale()
  return u'Libert\ + [Unicode] + "'"
```

I'm using this to create labels in ArcGIS.

This isn't working and I've played around with the return statement a bit, but I can't seem to get it to work....or really know if what I'm trying to do should work.

Basically, if I do get it to work, I want to store unicode in a field in an access table, so I can define a python function from it.

But then again, maybe I am way out to lunch on what I'm trying to attempt here.

Any suggestions are welcome! Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a slight misconception about the nature of Unicode. Unicode is something that exists strictly within the confines of your Python program. When you write data to a file -- or to a field in a database table -- you must encode that data.

With that foundation let's move on to the code. The two lines related to `locale` aren't doing anything productive at the moment. I suspect what you wanted to do is something more like:

```
import locale

# if you're on Windows in the US most likely 
# the following is returned: ('en_US', 'cp1252')
deflang, defencoding = locale.getdefaultlocale() 

# now that you have encoded your data (from Unicode) 
# you may commit it to the database 
write_this_to_db = u'Libert\u00e9'.encode(defencoding)
# -> 'Libert\xe9'
```

Comment: Thanks Bernie! I had a feeling ym udnerstanding of unicode wasn't exact, but it looks like I wasn't far off. I just started reading about it today after a request came through to work with it. I tried you snidbit, made a couple adjustments and it works for what I need. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: You're most welcome. Glad I could nudge you in the proper direction.

Comment: Oh hey, actually, I think I missed something. I don't want to hardcode the 'Libert\u00e9' portion of write_this_to_db = u'Libert\u00e9'.encode(defencoding). I want to set that field as a variable. For example In the field I have the python unicode source code (i.e. u00e9 as a string). I want to concatenate that field into the variable you set (if this is possible) Can I do something like write_this_to_db = u'Libert\+[unicode]'.encode(defencoding) where [unicode] is the name of my field so I can cursor search through create multiple outputs?

Comment: Sure. Try: `u'Libert{}'.format(u'\u00e9')`, or w/ a variable: `your_unicode = u'\u00e9'; u'Libert{}'.format(your_unicode)`